# NextJS axios Request failed with status code 403

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, axios, strapi

I am developing an app using NextJS and Strapi

In the NextJS fetching data from Strapi using Axios

```
Next: 14.0.4
Axios: ^1.6.5
Strapi: 4.17.1
Node: 18.17.0
```

code

```
import axios from 'axios'
const apiKey = 'xxxxxxxx';
const apiURL = 'http://localhost:1337/api';
const axiosClient = axios.create({
    baseURL:apiURL,
    Headers:{
        Authorization:`Bearer ${apiKey}`
    }
});
const getLatestProducts= ()=>axiosClient.get('/products');
export default{getLatestProducts}
```

getting error

```
'Request failed with status code 403'
```

but when using the same token with Thunder client and in next js trying the same token with fetches API getting data successfully only issues with Axios

can anyone help with this
Thanks in Advance

Comment: `Headers` != `headers` https://axios-http.com/docs/instance

Answer (score 1):

Simple, the `headers` property should be provided in lowercase as can be seen inside [the official documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/instance).

```js
import axios, { type AxiosResponse } from 'axios';

const API_KEY: string = 'xxxxxxxx';
const API_URL: string = 'xxxxxxxx';

const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_URL,
  headers: { Authorization:`Bearer ${apiKey}` },
});

export async function getLatestProducts(): Promise<AxiosResponse> {
  const response = await client.get('/products');
  return response;
}
```

---

When looking at your code I have noticed some things:

- Never provide your api key as string as this can be abused easily.
- Start using [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/), so errors like this do not happen to you.